# Работаю над программой аналогом SQL в C++ Возникло исключение: нарушение прав доступа для чтения _Pnext, хотя данные записываются нормально

Tags: c++

```
void FindAllDatabaseColumns_1(const DatabaseInfo& pDatabaseInfo, string pDatabaseName, map<int, string>* pColumns, DatabaseInfo* pDatabaseColumns)
{
    string DatabaseColumns = "";
    map<int, string> lColumns;
    int lCounter = 1;
    DatabaseInfo lDatabaseColumns;
    lDatabaseColumns = *pDatabaseColumns;
    for (const Knot* p = pDatabaseInfo.begin(); p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        if (p->DatabaseName == pDatabaseName)
        {
            lColumns.insert(make_pair(lCounter, p->DatabaseColumn));
            lDatabaseColumns.AddColumn(p->DatabaseName, p->DatabaseColumn, p->ColumnTypeOfData);
            DatabaseColumns = DatabaseColumns + "|" + p->DatabaseColumn;
            lCounter++;
        }
    }
    DatabaseColumns = DatabaseColumns + "|";
    *pDatabaseColumns = lDatabaseColumns;
    *pColumns = lColumns;
    for (auto& IColumns : lColumns)
    {
        cout << IColumns.first << "\t" << IColumns.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Мой класс - где написано `DatabaseInfo` . Честно, там много кода, но он состоит на прототипе списка. Вот **header** класса может чем-то помочь...
Если надо, могу загрузить остальной код проекта.

[image: DatabaseInfo.h]

Вот сама ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Честно, было бы интересно узнать, почему выдает ошибку, чтобы потом делать всё правильно и с пониманием работы **C++**!

Comment: Где-то ошиблись при работе с указателями. Можно попробовать подрубить [address sanitizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170). Если хотите, чтобы мы помогли дебажить, соорудите [mcve].

Comment: Если вам разрешено использовать стандартные контейнеры, то непонятно, зачем вы руками делаете связные списки. Взяли бы `std::list`.

Comment: Просто мне нужно подрубить потом некоторые функции и как сказал препод с помощью std::list не получится, поетому пришлось создавать вот такие связные списки(

Comment: Понял, надо будет проанализирывать что пошло не так вашым методом минимального воспроизводимого примера!

Comment: Так смотрите  я нашел ошыбку. Все из-за того что я пишу *pDatabaseColumns = lDatabaseColumns;, только тогда вопрос как мне по другому присвоить значения указателю на pDatabaseColumns, ибо по другому с функцией Add с моего класа оно не работало(выдавала ошыбку из-за типа переменной)

Comment: Все вопрос отпал. Надо было использывать
 pDatabaseColumns->AddColumn(p->DatabaseName, p->DatabaseColumn, p->ColumnTypeOfData);
Вместо присвоений и *pDatabaseColumns = lDatabaseColumns; и записи в класс lDatabaseColumns. 
Спасибо за совет узнал немного нового про ооп)

Comment: Сыграла злая шутка того что я новичок в с++)

Answer (score 0):

вопрос отпал. Надо было использывать:

```
pDatabaseColumns->AddColumn(p->DatabaseName, p->DatabaseColumn, p->ColumnTypeOfData);
```

вместо присвоений и:

```
*pDatabaseColumns = lDatabaseColumns;
```

и записи в класс `lDatabaseColumns`.

```
void FindAllDatabaseColumns_1(const DatabaseInfo& pDatabaseInfo, string pDatabaseName, map<int, string>* pColumns, DatabaseInfo *pDatabaseColumns)
{
    string DatabaseColumns = "";
    map<int, string> lColumns;
    int lCounter = 1;
    DatabaseInfo lDatabaseColumns;
    //lDatabaseColumns = *pDatabaseColumns; //и возможно из-за этой
    for (const Node* p = pDatabaseInfo.begin(); p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        if (p->DatabaseName == pDatabaseName)
        {
            lColumns.insert(make_pair(lCounter, p->DatabaseColumn));
            //lDatabaseColumns.AddColumn(p->DatabaseName, p->DatabaseColumn, p->ColumnTypeOfData);
            pDatabaseColumns->AddColumn(p->DatabaseName, p->DatabaseColumn, p->ColumnTypeOfData);

            DatabaseColumns = DatabaseColumns + "|" + p->DatabaseColumn;
            lCounter++;
        }
    }
    DatabaseColumns = DatabaseColumns + "|";
    //*pDatabaseColumns = lDatabaseColumns; //вот из-за этой строки ошыбка
    *pColumns = lColumns; 
    for (auto& IColumns : lColumns)
    {
        cout << IColumns.first << "\t" << IColumns.second << endl;
    }
}
```